# How can I end a 'try' loop in 'while' loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm in trouble about how to end a 'try' loop, which is occurred since I have the 'try', here is the code:

```
import time

class exe_loc:
    mem = ''
    lib = ''
    main = ''

def wizard():
    while True:
        try:
            temp_me = input('Please specify the full directory of the memory, usually it will be a folder called "mem"> ' )
            if temp_me is True:
                exe_loc.mem = temp_me
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print('Error value! Please run this configurator again!')
                sys.exit()
            temp_lib = input('Please specify the full directory of the library, usually it will be a folder called "lib"> ')
            if temp_lib is True:
                exe_loc.lib = temp_lib
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print('Invalid value! Please run this configurator again!')
                sys.exit()
            temp_main = input('Please specify the full main executable directory, usually it will be app main directory> ')
            if temp_main is True:
                exe_loc.main = temp_main
                time.sleep(1)
```

I tried end it by using `break`, `pass`, and I even leaves it empty what I get is `Unexpected EOF while parsing`, I searched online and they said it is caused when the code blocks were not completed. Please show me if any of my code is wrong, thanks.

Btw, I'm using python 3 and I don't know how to be more specific for this question, kindly ask me if you did not understand. Sorry for my poor english.

EDIT: Solved by removing the `try` because I'm not using it, but I still wanna know how to end a `try` loop properly, thanks.

Comment: this is not a valid Python syntax & `try` does not create a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't the `break`, it's the overall, high-level shape of your `try` clause.

A `try` requires either an `except` or a `finally` block. You have neither, which means your `try` clause is never actually complete. So python keeps looking for the next bit until it reaches EOF (End Of File), at which point it complains.

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) explain in more detail, but basically you need either:

```
try:
    do_stuff_here()
finally:
    do_cleanup_here()  # always runs, even if the above raises an exception
```

or

```
try:
    do_stuff_here()
except SomeException:
    handle_exception_here() # if do_stuff_here raised a SomeException
```

(You can also have *both* the `except` and `finally`.) If you don't need either the cleanup or the exception handling, that's even easier: just get rid of the `try` altogether, and have the block go directly under that `while True`.

Finally, as a terminology thing: `try` is not a loop. A loop is a bit of code that gets executed multiple times -- it loops. The `try` gets executed once. It's a "clause," not a "loop."

Answer (score 2):

You have to also 'catch' the exception with the `except` statement, otherwise the try has no use.

So if you do something like:

```
 try:
    # some code here
 except Exception:
    # What to do if specified error is encountered
```

This way if anywhere in your try block an exception is raised it will not break your code, but it will be catched by your except.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply. So did you mean I must specify a `except` in order to end a `try` properly?

Comment: @RexLeong, yes indeed. And fyi, it is a try statement, not  a loop

Comment: @SvenHakvoort I'm guessing you spend most of your time in Java or a similar language? :-) In python, I believe the standard terminology is "raising" an exception, not "throwing." (I made the same slip-up, since I mostly program in Java.)